# Hey, I am trying to build a custom environment and training an agent on that

Tags: tensorflow, environment, reinforcement-learning, openai-api, stable-baselines

at this line:

```py
model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)
```

It raises an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[200], line 2
      1 log_path = '/Users/mafaz2/Desktop/open cv test/Training/Logs'
----> 2 model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env, verbose=1, tensorboard_log=log_path)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/ppo/ppo.py:102, in PPO.__init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, n_steps, batch_size, n_epochs, gamma, gae_lambda, clip_range, clip_range_vf, normalize_advantage, ent_coef, vf_coef, max_grad_norm, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, target_kl, tensorboard_log, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model)
     75 def __init__(
     76     self,
     77     policy: Union[str, Type[ActorCriticPolicy]],
   (...)
     99     _init_setup_model: bool = True,
    100 ):
--> 102     super().__init__(
    103         policy,
    104         env,
    105         learning_rate=learning_rate,
    106         n_steps=n_steps,
    107         gamma=gamma,
    108         gae_lambda=gae_lambda,
    109         ent_coef=ent_coef,
    110         vf_coef=vf_coef,
    111         max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
    112         use_sde=use_sde,
    113         sde_sample_freq=sde_sample_freq,
    114         tensorboard_log=tensorboard_log,
    115         policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs,
    116         verbose=verbose,
    117         device=device,
    118         seed=seed,
    119         _init_setup_model=False,
    120         supported_action_spaces=(
    121             spaces.Box,
    122             spaces.Discrete,
    123             spaces.MultiDiscrete,
    124             spaces.MultiBinary,
    125         ),
    126     )
    128     # Sanity check, otherwise it will lead to noisy gradient and NaN
    129     # because of the advantage normalization
    130     if normalize_advantage:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/on_policy_algorithm.py:76, in OnPolicyAlgorithm.__init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, n_steps, gamma, gae_lambda, ent_coef, vf_coef, max_grad_norm, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, tensorboard_log, monitor_wrapper, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model, supported_action_spaces)
     53 def __init__(
     54     self,
     55     policy: Union[str, Type[ActorCriticPolicy]],
   (...)
     73     supported_action_spaces: Optional[Tuple[spaces.Space, ...]] = None,
     74 ):
---> 76     super().__init__(
     77         policy=policy,
     78         env=env,
     79         learning_rate=learning_rate,
     80         policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs,
     81         verbose=verbose,
     82         device=device,
     83         use_sde=use_sde,
     84         sde_sample_freq=sde_sample_freq,
     85         support_multi_env=True,
     86         seed=seed,
     87         tensorboard_log=tensorboard_log,
     88         supported_action_spaces=supported_action_spaces,
     89     )
     91     self.n_steps = n_steps
     92     self.gamma = gamma

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py:160, in BaseAlgorithm.__init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, policy_kwargs, tensorboard_log, verbose, device, support_multi_env, monitor_wrapper, seed, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, supported_action_spaces)
    158 if env is not None:
    159     env = maybe_make_env(env, self.verbose)
--> 160     env = self._wrap_env(env, self.verbose, monitor_wrapper)
    162     self.observation_space = env.observation_space
    163     self.action_space = env.action_space

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py:209, in BaseAlgorithm._wrap_env(env, verbose, monitor_wrapper)
    207     if verbose >= 1:
    208         print("Wrapping the env in a DummyVecEnv.")
--> 209     env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
    211 # Make sure that dict-spaces are not nested (not supported)
    212 check_for_nested_spaces(env.observation_space)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py:27, in DummyVecEnv.__init__(self, env_fns)
     25 def __init__(self, env_fns: List[Callable[[], gym.Env]]):
     26     self.envs = [fn() for fn in env_fns]
---> 27     if len(set([id(env.unwrapped) for env in self.envs])) != len(self.envs):
     28         raise ValueError(
     29             "You tried to create multiple environments, but the function to create them returned the same instance "
     30             "instead of creating different objects. "
   (...)
     35             "Please read https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1151 for more information."
     36         )
     37     env = self.envs[0]

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py:27, in <listcomp>(.0)
     25 def __init__(self, env_fns: List[Callable[[], gym.Env]]):
     26     self.envs = [fn() for fn in env_fns]
---> 27     if len(set([id(env.unwrapped) for env in self.envs])) != len(self.envs):
     28         raise ValueError(
     29             "You tried to create multiple environments, but the function to create them returned the same instance "
     30             "instead of creating different objects. "
   (...)
     35             "Please read https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1151 for more information."
     36         )
     37     env = self.envs[0]

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gym/core.py:238, in Wrapper.__getattr__(self, name)
    234 if name.startswith("_"):
    235     raise AttributeError(
    236         "attempted to get missing private attribute '{}'".format(name)
    237     )
--> 238 return getattr(self.env, name)

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'unwrapped'``
```

I tried building a class:

```py
class shower:
    
    def __init__ (self):
        self.Action_Space = Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = Box(low = 0 , high = 100 ,shape = (1,))
        
        self.state = 38+random.randint(-3 , 3)
        self.shower_length = 60
    
    def step(self , action):
        
        self.state += action - 1
        self.shower_length -=1
        
        if self.state >= 37 and self.state <= 39:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1
            
        if self.shower_length <= 0 :
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        info = {}
        
        return self.state , reward , done , info
        
    def render(self):
        pass
    
    def reset(self):
        self.state = np.array([38+random.randint(-3 , 3) ]).astype(float)
        self.shower_length = 60
        return self.state
    `
```

and training PPO over that, but it resulted in an error

Comment: what is `env `?

Comment: did you try reading the error message? what is up with: Please read https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1151 for more information.